# What is the meaning of view in Flask view function?

Tags: flask, model-view-controller

I know how the routing system works in Flask, but I don't know why the function with `route()` decorator called **view function**. Does it relate to **View** in MVC architectural pattern? However, in this [tutorial](https://realpython.com/blog/python/the-model-view-controller-mvc-paradigm-summarized-with-legos/), the view function was included into **Controller** in MVC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Werkzeug (the library that handles the WSGI routing functions) states you can call them views or controllers, per your preference. See the [*URL Routing* section](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/routing/#module-werkzeug.routing):

> When it comes to combining multiple controller or view functions (however you want to call them), you need a dispatcher.

Werkzeug is based on the [*routes* library](http://routes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which in turn was inspired by Ruby on Rails. Rails used the term *views* to reference the V in the MVC model. But clearly, the terminology has become muddled.